# Add text message under "Add new comment" title

Tags: 8, theming, comments

I would like to add a disclaimer message under "Add new comment" title and above the form in drupal 8 site. I changed the help text on this path /admin/structure/types/manage/article/fields/node.article.comment but nothing changed.
Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `field--comment.html.twig` template.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21comment%21templates%21field--comment.html.twig/8.8.x

```
<section{{ attributes }}>
  {% if comments and not label_hidden %}
    {{ title_prefix }}
    <h2{{ title_attributes }}>{{ label }}</h2>
    {{ title_suffix }}
  {% endif %}

  {{ comments }}

  {% if comment_form %}
    <h2{{ content_attributes }}>{{ 'Add new comment'|t }}</h2>
    // you can add your markup here
    {{ comment_form }}
  {% endif %}

</section>
```

**clear the cache after add new template file**